# sysdate format not working in where clause with time

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime, plsql

I am trying to run following query on oracle at PL/SQL developer to select a list of time slots between current time and end of the day:

```
SELECT T.VISIT_DATE
  FROM REGISTRATION.VU_SCHEDULE T
 WHERE T.VISIT_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
 AND   TO_DATE('27-MARCH-2020 23:59:59', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
 ORDER BY VISIT_DATE
```

but it gives me result of whole day instead of current time of day

```
    VISIT_DATE
1   3/27/2020 9:00:00 AM
2   3/27/2020 9:15:00 AM
3   3/27/2020 9:30:00 AM
4   3/27/2020 9:45:00 AM
5   3/27/2020 10:00:00 AM
6   3/27/2020 10:15:00 AM
7   3/27/2020 10:30:00 AM
8   3/27/2020 10:45:00 AM
9   3/27/2020 11:00:00 AM
10  3/27/2020 11:15:00 AM
11  3/27/2020 11:30:00 AM
12  3/27/2020 11:45:00 AM
```

e.g if current time is 11:00 AM then it should give result from current time.

I've tried trunc(sysdate) but it doesn't work

**NOTE:**

The condition must have date and time from now to the end of the day with format.

Comment: **NEVER**, ever call `to_date()` on a value that is already a date. That will first convert the `date` value to a `varchar` just to convert that `varchar` back to a `date` which it was to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> must have date and time from now to the end of the day with format.

You could do:

```
where t.visit_date >= sysdate and t.visit_date < trunc(sysdate) + 1
```

Rationale:

- `sysdate` gives you the current date/time, that represents the lower bound of the interval
- `trunc(sysdate)` is the beginninig of the current day (today at midnight), to which you can add `1` to get the beginning of the next day; this is the (exclusive) upper bound of the range

Note that there is no point applying `to_date()` to function `sysdate`, that produces a date alreay.

Comment: this works perfect. I've been looking for this for almost more then 3 hours didn't know that it works like this too. thanks.